# Division error in Python Pandas: libmkl_vml_avx.so: undefined symbol: mkl_serv_getenv

Tags: python, pandas

I just moved from Python 2.7 to 3.5. Recently I have been working with the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob as g
import numpy as np

archivos = g.glob('/compartido/FICHEROS_IC/MODELOS/archivosXML/ConvertidosXML/*_LEITURAS_*.csv')
vuelta=0

for archiv in archivos:
    a=os.path.basename(archiv) 
    nomarch= os.path.splitext(a)[0] 
    nombre = os.path.splitext(archiv)[0] 

    df = pd.read_csv(archiv, sep=",") 
    d = pd.to_datetime(df['DATA_LEITURA'], format="%Y%m%d")
    df['FECHA_LECTURA'] = d.dt.date
    del df['DATA_LEITURA']       

    order = df.sort_values(['NR_CPE','FECHA_LECTURA', 'HORA_LEITURA'], ascending=True)    

    grouped = order.groupby('NR_CPE')

    order["CONSUMO"]= order.VALOR_LEITURA - order.groupby(['NR_CPE'])['VALOR_LEITURA'].shift(1).fillna(0)
    order["DIAS"]= order.FECHA_LECTURA - order.groupby(['NR_CPE'])['FECHA_LECTURA'].shift(1)

    order["DIAS"]= order["DIAS"].replace('NaT',0)
    order["DIAS"]= order["DIAS"].astype('timedelta64[D]')

    numday = grouped['DIAS'].size() > 1    
    sumday = grouped['DIAS'].sum()  
    day = sumday[numday]

    numberocons = grouped['CONSUMO'].size() > 1 
    sumconsu = grouped['CONSUMO'].sum()    
    consu = sumconsu[numberocons]


    canu = (consu/day) * 365 

    Fdias = day.map('{:.0f}'.format)
    Fcanu = canu.replace('inf',0).map('{:.2f}'.format)
```

This code was working well when I had both python 2.7 and 3.5. This week I removed python 2.7 from my system and now I have this error:

> python: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numexpr/../../../libmkl_vml_avx.so:
>   undefined symbol: mkl_serv_getenv

I found that I've got the error in the following instruction:

```
canu = (consu/day) * 365 #Anual consumption
```

Why is this happening and any idea of how to fix it?

I'm running on Python 3.5.1 | Anaconda 4.1.0 (64-bit)

Comment: hi @juliana-rivera, have you tried that `conda install --yes mkl mkl-service`?

Comment: or that `conda install mkl-rt`